# Oracle. Correct offset in timestamp with timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm executing this select now

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(to_timestamp('2015-08-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'Asia/Singapore') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
FROM DUAL
```

I'm interesting in `time`, in this case time is `02:00 AM`, because `Singapore` has difference between `UTC` in `8 hours`.
Everything is ok, but, if I'm changing month from `08` to `01`, I'm expecting to get `03:00 AM`, because it was winter time in `Singapore`, but I get 02:00 AM again.
 So the question is, how could I get the correct result with correct offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Asia/Singapore` does not have any Daylight saving times, see here: [Singapore Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time)

Crazy, Oracle implemented this list properly:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Asia/Singapore') AS TS FROM DUAL;
TS                                      
----------------------------------------
08.01.2015 10:00:00.000000000 +08:00    
1 row selected.

SELECT FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Asia/Singapore') AS TS FROM DUAL;
TS                                      
----------------------------------------
08.01.1970 10:00:00.000000000 +07:30    
1 row selected.

SELECT FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('1943-01-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Asia/Singapore') AS TS FROM DUAL;
TS                                      
----------------------------------------
08.01.1943 10:00:00.000000000 +09:00    
1 row selected.

SELECT FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('1940-01-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Asia/Singapore') AS TS FROM DUAL;
TS                                      
----------------------------------------
08.01.1940 10:00:00.000000000 +07:20    
1 row selected.

SELECT FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('1920-01-08 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'Asia/Singapore') AS TS FROM DUAL;
TS                                      
----------------------------------------
08.01.1920 10:00:00.000000000 +07:00    
1 row selected.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my fault about Singapore time, thanks a lot!